# MySQL stored function with 2 paramets

Tags: mysql

I want to create a stored function using MySQL that takes 2 parameters date and hour and converts them into a date time from 2 columns inside a table.

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `data_formatata`(data TEXT,ora TEXT) RETURNS text CHARSET latin1
    DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN

```
set @data = DATE_FORMAT(data, '%d,%m,%Y');
set @ora = DATE_FORMAT(ora, '%h,%i,%s');

RETURN CONCAT_WS('',@data,@ora);
```

END

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in one of these two ways, depending on the types of the input parameters (so I think you would prefer the second way):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION DATE_TIME
(DATE_VALUE DATE,
TIME_VALUE TIME)
RETURNS TIMESTAMP
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
RETURN TIMESTAMP(TIMESTAMP(DATE_VALUE)+TIME(TIME_VALUE));
END$$
DELIMITER;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION DATE_TIME_2
(DATE_VALUE TEXT,
TIME_VALUE TEXT)
RETURNS TIMESTAMP
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
RETURN TIMESTAMP(TIMESTAMP(DATE_VALUE)+TIME(TIME_VALUE));
END$$
DELIMITER;
```